# Changing coordinate to smoothen a function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be an open neighborhood of the origin $0$, and let $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function which is smooth on $U\setminus\left\{0\right\}$. Let's say that $f$ is *smoothable at* $0$ if there is a homeomorphism $\phi:U'\to U$ between $U$ and another open neithborhood $U'\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ of $0$ such that $\phi(0)=0$, $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism on $U'\setminus \left\{0\right\}$, and $f\circ\phi : U'\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth, even at $0$.

My question is, are there some conditions which we may test on a given $f$ which are preferably equivalent to $f$ being smoothable at $0$? If equivalence is too hard, are there known sufficient conditions and necessary conditions for $f$ being smoothable at $0$?

Comment: By Sard's theorem, a smoothable function has inverse image of any measurable set measureable, and inverse image of any value a measure zero set, except for values on a measure zero set.